# ImageMagick converts out of order

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have 100 images named img0.jpg to img99.jpg to be converted to a pdf file. problem is

```
convert img*.jpg out.pdf
```

adds pages in the order of 1,11,2,22,etc. how is order defined in imagemagick?

Comment: Images are accessed in alphabetic order from your directory. You need to rename your images with leading zeroes, img01, img02 ... img99 in order to get the processed in that order.

Comment: Order is "defined" in imagemagick to be the order given in the command line. Your real question should be: how is "img*.jpg" expanded? What order does the shell use for files which match the pattern. (Answer: the shell includes the matching files names in dictionary order, according to your LOCALE.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either number your pages with zero-padded numbers like this so **ImageMagick** takes them in order:

```
img000.jpg
img001.jpg
img002.jpg
...
img098.jpg
```

Then your original command should work.

---

Or, have `bash` enumerate the files in order and feed the names into **ImageMagick** like this:

```
magick img{0..99}.jpg result.pdf
```

Or:

```
for file in img{0..99}.jpg; do echo $file; done | magick @- result.pdf
```

---

Or rename your files as per the first example above, but using Perl `rename`:

```
rename --dry-run 's/\D//g; $_=sprintf("f-%05d.jpg",$_)' f*jpg
```

**Sample Output**

```
'f0.jpg' would be renamed to 'f-00000.jpg'
'f1.jpg' would be renamed to 'f-00001.jpg'
'f10.jpg' would be renamed to 'f-00010.jpg'
'f11.jpg' would be renamed to 'f-00011.jpg'
'f12.jpg' would be renamed to 'f-00012.jpg'
```

---

You may have `ls -v` available to you, in which case you can try:

```
magick $(ls -v img*jpg) result.pdf
```